# Microsoft tool to see Windows TCP internals (congestion window, etc)

Tags: windows, networking, tcp

I hope this isn't too vague a question: I remember a tool from Microsoft that was able to show me all kinds of internal TCP variables, like congestion window, etc.  I remember that I needed to activate some extra statistics keeping and then reboot Windows and that is was able to show me this data in real time for an active connection.  It must be kinda old, maybe 5 or more years already.  I guess it was part of some SDK or resource kit (I've looked through the resource kit and the SDK 10.0.17763.0 without success.

Does anybody know something like this?

Comment: Possibly related: https://serverfault.com/questions/942039/how-can-i-see-a-tcp-sessions-properties-congestion-window-size-current-slow-st?rq=1